# How many rolls of two 6-sided dice to get the sum of 12?

Tags: probability-distributions

What are the probabilities of getting a sum of 12 on rolling two 6-sided dice. On the first roll i think the chance is 2%, but how many rolls will it take for the probability to be 50% or 80%?

Comment: I.e., the chance increases the more times you roll the two dice, yes?

Comment: I am sorry but I am unable to understand the question. Could you elaborate more because I do not want to assume the wrong things and give you an incorrect solution.

Comment: Why do you think the probability of a 12 increases with the number of rolls?

Comment: I understand that the probability remains at 2 or 3% for EACH roll. But with the greater number of rolls, how does that affect the chance of getting 12? So for example, suppose I roll the pair of dice 10 times. Does that mean the chance is 10 x the 2-3% = 20-30%? So if i roll the dice 20 times, the probability of hitting a 12 just once is greater?

Answer (score 2):

The probability of not getting 12 on a given roll is 35/36, so the probability of not getting 12 at any time during n rolls is $q_n=(35/36)^n$.  What you seem to be looking for is $p_n=1-q_n$.

Answer (score 1):

On the first roll u get either 1/36 chance of getting a 12 or 35/36 of not getting. So to get in second chance u have probability (35/36)*(1/36) and to get  in third try (35/36)*(35/36)*(1/36). The two (35/36) is probability of losing in first two tries. So add the terms of GP of general term (1/36)*(35/36)^r till some number n to get probability of getting 12 till n tries.